# Plugin Post Type pagination not working - Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using Event Calendar WD plugin to post events on my page
(The post type of the plugin defined is 'ecwd_event').
I managed to query the posts in the template events.php, however, the pagination isn't working : when I click on page 2, it redirects to 404 page even though on page 1 it shows 4 posts of this post type.
Please help.

Here is my query code :

```
    <?php
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

    $args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'post_type' => 'ecwd_event',
    'paged'     => $paged

    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);

    ?>
```

Here is my pagination code :

```
        <footer class="pagination">
        <ul class="pagination-list">
        <?php

        $big = 999999999;

        echo( paginate_links( array(

            'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
            'format' => '?paged=%#%',
            'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
            'total' => $the_query->max_num_pages
            )));

            wp_reset_postdata();


        ?>


        </ul>
</footer>
```

Comment: make sure you have set permalinks properly.

Comment: I did, the first page shows 4 news and it redirects to the permalink well. ( That's why I don't show the code here but only code for query and pagination )
The problem here is when I click on page 2 to see older posts it takes me to 404 page - which is now my current issue.